# HTTP request failing occasional with EOFException in Java

Tags: java, http, post, eofexception

I am doing a POST call in Java to an external device. Sometimes, and only sometimes it fails with EOFException. I increased the timeout value however it keeps thorwing the EOFException. Any idea what could cause that?

```
Error processing POST 2 request java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.io.EOFException: HttpConnectionOverHTTP@1030fd::SocketChannelEndPoint@1bef5c3
{l=/192.168.2.30:53792,r=/192.168.2.27:80,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=85/0}
{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnectionOverHTTP@1030fd(l:/192.168.2.30:53792 <-> r:/192.168.2.27:80,closed=false)
=>HttpChannelOverHTTP@b7ea87(exchange=HttpExchange@e3564c{req=HttpRequest[POST /status.cgi HTTP/1.1]@1231335[TERMINATED/null] 
res=HttpResponse[null 0 null]@15deebf[PENDING/null]})[send=HttpSenderOverHTTP@a3d281(req=QUEUED,snd=COMPLETED,failure=null)
[HttpGenerator@babb2f{s=START}],recv=HttpReceiverOverHTTP@11dbd76(rsp=IDLE,failure=null)[HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1}]]
```

Comment: Hard to answer.  It could be many things.  You need to identify which requests fail, and if there is a difference between them and the others that do not, if the errors happens to only those requests, or random (Perhaps network issue).   It could be the Request/Response payload might be too big for some of them? :)  Honestly I would start with logging as much as I can to understand if there is a pattern here or not.

Comment: Thank you. It is always the same call. Basically the call gets the actual status of an IoT device, After a while it sometimes fails, then it works again. In my opion it is a network instability as the device is connected via Wifi.